# Angular 7 CLI build: how to omit templates to be able to use MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-cli, ng-build

I'm evaluating the lastest bits of Angular (7+) and CLI. I've done parts of the 'Tour of Heroes' tutorial. I can run 'ng build' to get the production bits.

However, an important requisite is the use of MVC views for component templates.

So instead of

> templateUrl: './app.component.html'

I want to use

> templateUrl: '/Template/Index'

for various reasons (translated templates being one). I do understand this is not the 'pure' Angular way of doing thing.

With this code in place, 'ng build' no longer works:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
>
> Module not found : error : Can't resolve './/Template/Index' in 'D:\Angular\TourOfHeroes\TourOfHeroes\src\app'

I've searched for hours how to omit building the templates, but I can't find an answer. ng eject is depricated. It guides me to ngx-build-plus, but I don't see how this can help me.

What steps should I take to get this working?

EDIT:

Question [How to using MVC views (*.cshtml) as templates in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634916) is not related. I know how to use MVC views in Angular. What I don't know is how to tell 'ng build' to omit these templates (as they are not static at all).

Comment: Why do you want to use angular if you're already using .net views?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to using MVC views (\*.cshtml) as templates in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634916/how-to-using-mvc-views-cshtml-as-templates-in-angular-2)

Comment: @Friso: No, not a duplicate. I know how to use MVC views with Angular, but I can't get it to work with 'ng build' to build production bits.

Comment: under MVC views you mean .cshtml files, with razor syntax?

Comment: @robert: Yes. They are processed on the server, delivering Angular templates (as in 'Hi {{firstName}}') to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to switch to webpack/rollup/systemjs-builder in order to create builds omitting baking in templates. Angular CLI doesn't support such scenario.

One caveat - you will be building in development mode, aot doesn't support dynamic templates (not in straightforward way)

Comment: Hi Keukue, thanks for taking the time to answer this (relatively) old question! I will look into this. Do you have any experience replacing Angular CLI yourself? Do you happen to know a good tutorial that should get me started?

Comment: I tried all the mentioned tools. The best option would be wepback. There's bunch of tutorials online. I followed few of them, as each pertains to different versions of angular, typescript and other libraries you use.
The most promising one I'd recommend is https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-angular-7-a-complete-guide-9a23c879f471/